# Nice free tool to create UML Communication (=Collaboration) diagrams

Tags: uml, diagram, tool-uml, staruml, collaboration-diagram

UML 1 uses the name Collaboration Diagram. UML 2 uses the name Communication Diagram. [In this link you can find the definition and one nice example](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/communicationDiagram.htm). [Here you can find a nice reference about how to create them](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/communication-diagrams-reference.html).

Unfortunately, I didn't find this diagram in the software I have been using lately: [DIA](http://dia-installer.de/). I think it is not available in [WhiteStarUML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/whitestaruml/) either. There is a tutorial in the help, but I wasn't able to make it work. As WhiteStarUML is a fork of StartUML, maybe it is just not done yet.

[image: WhiteStarUML Screenshot]

*WhiteStarUML Screenshot: there is a folder for Collaboration Diagram but not a file inside to double click it to create it (like the Class Diagrams or UseCase Diagrams)*

What your favourite free tool to create those diagrams?

Comment: If you can't find something for this type of diagram specifically, I'd recommend yEd as a general diagram tool. You can customize it to do pretty much anything. I'm not sure if it's free, but it is gratis.

Comment: @GVH, yEd seems a easy way to paint any diagram... But I didn't find any symbol to draw [the secuential messages](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/communication-diagrams-reference.html) with it :(

Comment: Do you mean the edge that has the arrow in addition to some text? You can make a custom edge like that. Put down any edge, add a label, edit the label, change the icon to a picture of an arrow, set the rotation to auto-rotate, etc. Then save it is a custom shape and you can re-use it.

Comment: OK @GVH, you're right. I did it. It could be another solution too...

Comment: It's not a great solution, I agree. Feels very hacky. However, I think the selection of programs in this space is disappointing. StarUML and family are too cluttered with features I don't want, and of the remainder yEd is the only solution I've found that comes close to having the right combination of ease-of-use and power.

Comment: So far is my best option @GVH, but let's wait if somebody tell us another possibility ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, free community edition of Visual Paradygm UML. Until you use one diagram for a project it even can be printed without water signs.

But the communication diagram is very simple, you could easily simulate it with some free diagraming tool. There are many of them, they are easy, simply try and find what you like - intuitivity is  too personal thing.

Comment: That arrow which goes together the message is not in every diagram tool. Of course you can put an arrow separately, but if you move something, the arrow won't move with it. Again, I like Visual Paradygm UML. You can [download the free edition here](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/freeumltool/). You can [see all the products of Visual Paradigm here](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/editions/).

Comment: @chelder I just compared several modelling tools last month. VP UML won the second place after EA from Sparx. VP has very weak free diagraming tools. And the guys don't even intent to change them, I asked their support about it. But as a free variant, their community edition is very good. But for free hand diagrams some open source diagraming tools would be better.

Comment: @chelder and why are you not checking answers? Not necessarily mine, but some? If we'll be greedy, our theme (uml) won't expand. And finally, we'll all lose on it.

Comment: Well, my idea was to give some time to receive some more answer. So anybody who looks for this topic (as I did in google, with no results) could see more viewpoints. But I guess you're right one more time!

Comment: @chelder I am not without vice in it, too. I am very forgetful and have to check from time to time my old posts for set upvotes to other posters... Normally the rule - waiting for more answers work. But not here on uml, where we have so few visitors. About 5 visits for a day at best! Only question that are visited by reviewers for closing get some more views.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be intuitive but in WhiteStarUML ones creates diagrams (including Collaboration Diagram) using the context menu of the Model Explorer (right click on a package) or chosing from the main menu "Model - Add Diagram". In the Diagram Explorer you only see the existing diagrams.

Comment: You're right, I could do it, but it is not intuitive at all! I think WhiteStartUML is a **good idea if we want to generate code automatically** from diagram. It is not the case though, so I prefer to use another more intuitive diagram tool if it is possible.